# MethodHandle Lookup facility

Tags: java, reflection, java-7

As far as JavaDoc states `MethodHandles.lookup()` returns facility that have ability to access the same method/functions/constructor as the caller of this function. Specifically, if the caller can access some private data, so as this MethodHandles.Lookup facility. Code below demonstrates that this is false. Where I get it wrong?

```
public class MethodHandlerAccessTest  {

        private static class NestedClass {
            private static void foo(){}
        }

        @Test
        public void testPrivateAccess() throws Throwable {
            NestedClass.foo();  //compiles and executes perfectly
            MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(void.class);
            MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
            MethodHandle mh = lookup.findStatic(NestedClass.class, "foo", type);
        }

 }
```

**Edit:**

This is what I get:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: member is private:
>   MethodHandlerAccessTest$NestedClass.foo()void, from
>   MethodHandlerAccessTest   at
>   java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:507)
>     at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.checkAccess(MethodHandles.java:1182)
>     at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.checkMethod(MethodHandles.java:1162)
>     at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.accessStatic(MethodHandles.java:591)
>     at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findStatic(MethodHandles.java:587)
>     at
>   MethodHandlerAccessTest.testPrivateAccess(MethodHandlerAccessTest.java:19)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that your test method doesn't *really* call `NestedClass.foo()`. This line:

```
NestedClass.foo();
```

... is actually transformed into a call to a *synthetic method* which is generated in `foo`, like this:

```
NestedClass.access$000();
```

Where `access$000` looks like this:

```
// Note package access
static void access$000() {
    foo();
}
```

You can validate this by using `javap -c` to look at the actual bytecode.

At the JVM level, your outer class doesn't have access to `foo()`. The Java compiler just *synthesizes* access to it by creating `access$000` and calling it from your outer class whenever the source code calls `foo()`.

At execution time, the reflection libraries *don't* do the same thing, hence your error.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I heard elsewhere about *synthetic fields/methods*, but I never really encounted with it. Why MethodHandle didn't simulate this behaviour? From the JavaDoc of lookup() method

`Returns a lookup object on the caller, which has the capability to access any method handle that the caller has access to, including direct method handles to private fields and methods. This lookup object is a capability which may be delegated to trusted agents.`

I expected to do it.

Comment: @alexsmail: The compiler can implement the synthetic method however it chooses to. I wouldn't *want* the JRE to try to do the same thing. It's important to distinguish between what the *language* allows you to do, and what the *bytecode* allows you to do. As far as the VM is concerned, you're not calling `foo()`, and you don't have access to do so. The language is able to give you "special" rights to do so by adding the extra method and calling that - but that's just a language concern. The caller (the outer class) really *doesn't* have access to `foo()` from the VM's perspective.

Comment: It's a bit late, but there's an easy fix. Replace `MethodHandles.lookup()` with `MethodHandles.lookup().in(NestedClass.class)`. When changing the context class between outer and inner classes this way, the private access capability is retained, so afterwards, accessing the `private` members of the nested class works. Besides that, starting with Java 11, this `access$...` stuff is not necessary anymore, but it also requires the code to be compiled with JDK 11 target.